# Magento: Fastest way to hide empty categories in Magento frontend?

Tags: magento, categories

What I'm trying to do seems trivial but I've been looking on Google for this for the past 3 hours and can't find it...

--> I'm just trying to list the categories of my website but hide those that are empty AND that all their subcategories are also empty (no products).

Shouldn't that be easy to do?? Everything I've found seems utterly complicated or custom-coded. Am I the only one that doesn't want to show empty categories?

Note: I'm using Magento 1.3.2.4, I don't want to manually hide categories in backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an article about that from Pratski :

[Display Only If There Are Products In The Category](https://web.archive.org/web/20100708160910/http://prattski.com/2008/12/17/magento-display-only-if-there-are-products-in-the-category)

Comment: Wow this is amazing, thanks a lot! It's a mystery why I couldn't easily find tutorial for this, it seems to me that the last thing you want to do is to manually hide/show categories in the backend, especially if you have 100+ catagories!

Comment: @Stevie check again pls.